# Different Link depending on Checkbox marked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create 2 containers, where one of them can only be selected an option which in this case is the product, and in the second container I need to have 3 checkboxes, where is the product variable. I need that when, for example, you select "product A" and the "Blue" variation, it gives me a link, but when I select "product B" and the "Blue" variation, it gives me another link and so on, needing 9 different urls

I've tried this code here, but i can make it work well

```html
<div class="container">
    <form>
    <div class="bundle-container-1">
        <label for="bundle1" class="bundle-header">Choose your bundle 2:</label>
        <div class="bundle-options">
            <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" data-url="http://www.yahoo.com">
                <input type="checkbox" id="bundle1-0" name="ch" value="0"><br>
                <label for="bundle1-0">3 Month Supply</label>
            </div>
            <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" data-url="http://www.youtube.com">
                <input type="checkbox" id="bundle2-0" name="ch" value="1">
                <label for="bundle2-0">6 Month Supply</label>
            </div>
            <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" data-url="https://shop.ozzihome.com/closet-pest-trap/oto-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="bundle3-0" name="ch" value="2">
                <label for="bundle3-0">12 Month Supply</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bundle-footer">
            <div class="bundle-price">$297 $169</div>
            <div class="bundle-save">SAVE 43%</div>
        <div class="bundle-container-2">
            <label for="bundle2" class="bundle-header">Choose your bundle 2:</label>
            <div class="bundle-options">
                <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" data-url="https://shop.ozzihome.com/closet-pest-trap/oto-1">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="bundle4-0" name="ch" value="4">
                    <label for="bundle4-0">3 Month Supply</label>
                </div>
                <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" data-url="https://shop.ozzihome.com/closet-pest-trap/oto-2-ag3eaeg">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbundle2" name="ch">
                    <label for="bundle5-0">6 Month Supply</label>
                </div>
                <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" data-url="https://shop.ozzihome.com/closet-pest-trap/oto-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbundle3" name="ch">
                    <label for="bundle6-0">12 Month Supply</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bundle-footer">
                <div class="bundle-price">$297 $169</div>
                <div class="bundle-save">SAVE 43%</div>
                <input type="button" class="buttontest" onclick="return newURL()" value="GO URL">
                <button class="add-to-cart" onclick="return newURL()" value="GO URL">Add to Cart - $499</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
const options = [
  {
    months: 3,
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
    price: 169,
    url: 'https://shop.ozzihome.com/closet-pest-trap/oto-1'
  },
  {
    months: 6,
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/400x400',
    price: 299,
    url: 'https://shop.ozzihome.com/closet-pest-trap/oto-2-ag3eaeg'
  },
  {
    months: 12,
    image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/500x500',
    price: 499,
    url: 'https://shop.ozzihome.com/closet-pest-trap/oto-3'
  }
];


const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll('.bundle-option');
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container img');
const addToCartBtn = document.querySelector('.add-to-cart');

// Update the active option when clicked
optionsList.forEach((option, index) => {
  option.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Remove the active class from all options
    optionsList.forEach(option => {
      option.classList.remove('active');
    });

    // Add active class to clicked option
    option.classList.add('active');

    // Update the image based on the selected option
    if (option.innerText.includes('3 Month')) {
      imageContainer.src = options[index].image;
    } else if (option.innerText.includes('6 Month')) {
      imageContainer.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x350';
    } else if (option.innerText.includes('12 Month')) {
      imageContainer.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/400x400';
    }

    // Update the price in the add to cart button
    addToCartBtn.textContent = `Add to Cart - $${options[index].price}`;

    // Update the URL in the add to cart button
    addToCartBtn.dataset.url = options[index].url;

    const bundle2Options = document.querySelectorAll('.bundle-container-2 .bundle-option');
    const addToCartBtn = document.querySelector('.add-to-cart');

bundle2Options.forEach((option, index) => {
  const checkbox = option.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (option.classList.contains('active') && checkbox.checked) {
      addToCartBtn.dataset.url = options[index].url + '-bundle2';
    } else {
      addToCartBtn.dataset.url = options[index].url;
    }
  });
});

  });
});



// Redirect to the selected option URL when Add to Cart button is clicked
addToCartBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.href = addToCartBtn.dataset.url;
});

url = new Array();
    url[0] = new Array();
    url[0][0] = '';
    url[0][1] = ''; 
    url[0][2] = 'http://www.cnn.com.br'; 
    url[0][3] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x350'; 
    url[0][4] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/400x400'; 
    url[1] = new Array();
    url[1][0] = 'http://www.g1.com.br';
    url[1][1] = 'http://www.msn.com';
    url[2] = new Array();
    url[2][0] = 'http://www.uol.com.br'; 
    url[2][1] = 'http://www.google.com';
    url[3] = new Array();
    url[3][0] = 'http://www.twitch.tv'; 
    url[3][1] = 'http://www.kabum.com.br';
    url[4] = new Array();
    url[4][0] = 'http://www.amazon.com'; 
    url[4][1] = 'http://www.aliexpress.com';
    url[5] = new Array();
    url[5][0] = 'http://www.nike.com.br'; 
    url[5][1] = 'http://www.booking.com';
    url[6] = new Array();
    url[6][0] = 'http://www.example.com';
    url[6][1] = 'http://www.anotherexample.com';

    function newURL(){
    d = document.forms[0];
    p1 = -1;
    p2 = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < d.ch.length; i++) {
        if (d.ch[i].checked) {
            if (p1 == -1) {
                p1 = i;
            } else if (p2 == -1) {
                p2 = i;
                break;
            } else {
                alert('Too many boxes checked!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (p1 == -1) {
        alert('No boxes checked!');
        return false;
    } else if (p2 == -1) {
        window.open(url[p1][0], '_self');
    } else {
        window.open(url[p1][p2 - 1], '_self');
    }
}


</script>

<script>

const checkboxes1 = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-bundle-1');
const checkboxes2 = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-bundle-2');

function handleCheckboxes1(e) {
  if (!e.target.checked) return;
  checkboxes1.forEach(checkbox => {
    if (checkbox !== e.target) {
      checkbox.checked = false;
    }
  });
}

function handleCheckboxes2(e) {
  if (!e.target.checked) return;
  checkboxes2.forEach(checkbox => {
    if (checkbox !== e.target) {
      checkbox.checked = false;
    }
  });
}

checkboxes1.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', handleCheckboxes1);
});

checkboxes2.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', handleCheckboxes2);
});



</script>
  

<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.image-container {
  width: 488px;
  height: 488px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bundle-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bundle-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-option.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #f45b69;
  color: #f45b69;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.add-to-cart {
  background-color: #f45b69;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.buttontest {
  background-color: #f45b69;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* teste de css pro 2 container */

.bundle-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bundle-options-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-option.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #f45b69;
  color: #f45b69;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.bundle-option label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


</style>
```

Comment: hi, welcome to StackOverflow. That's one big blob of code - please condense it down to a [mre] that shows just the problem in an isolated environment. Also, please use a **code snippet** (the [<>] button) to make it easier to test.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Your pasted code has multiple problems (for example miss 1 `<div>` tag, `</form>` must be before last `<div>` and `image-container` doesn't exist)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'ved put the code snippet in case of testing. I need to that only 1 checkbox in each container can be selected